# Bend a metal strip to a different axis

Tags: metal-folding, metalwork

How can I bend a metal strip (3 inches x 3 feet x 1/32th) in a different axis? I know it would need a few compound bends, but can't figure out the math. Preferably straight vends instead of just twisting it.

How long of a bend radius would be needed? The goal is to get it it from flat horizontally to vertical along the same horizontal plane.

How would the math change if it's a 2 inch strip across?

Comment: Twist seems easier and faster to be honest. You stick it in a vise get some pliers and twist, or preferably a clamp mounted on a rotating guide. I don't know why you need math. Cut out a strip of paper and bend it. But it looks like no amount of of 90 degree bends along a 45-degree line will do it. I think all your bends would just be approximating a twist which means a lot of bends shallow bends at small angles from the longitudinal axis which is difficult compared to just twisting.

Comment: @DKNguyen paper is too flexible and I can't get clean bend lines out of it. I figure it's like 3 to 7 bends at best with a break